# how to use props.img in react 18

Tags: reactjs, jsx, react-props

I'm new to React (following older tutorials, but trying to work within React 18) Using props, is there a best method to be able to import an image into App.jsx?

All the rest I am set on except this bit

`<img className="card-image" src={KatieZ} alt="Olympic athlete Katie Zaferes"/>`

in Card.jsx -->

```
import "../css/index.css"
import KatieZ from '../images/katie-zaferes.png'
import Star from '../images/star.png'

function Card(props) {

    return (
      <section className="experience-cards">
        <div className="experience-item">
            <img className="card-image" src={KatieZ} alt="Olympic athlete Katie Zaferes"/>
            <p className="experience-text">Sold Out</p>
        </div>
        <div className="description-below">
            <div className="rating">
                <img className="star" src={Star} alt="Rating star" width={15}/>
                <p>{props.rating}</p><span>({props.reviewCount}) • {props.country}</span>
            </div>
            <p class="item-description">{props.title}</p>
            <p className="item-price"><span className="item-price">From ${props.price}</span> /  person</p>
        </div>
      </section>
    )
  }
  
  export default Card
```

in App.jsx -->

```
import Card from './components/Card'

export default function App() {

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Navbar />
      <Hero />
      <Card 
        img="../images/katie-zaferes.png"
        rating="5.0"
        reviewCount={6}
        country="USA"
        title="Life lessons with Katie Zaferes"
        price={42}
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can import the Katiez image in the App component.. and pass the image as the value of img in  props instead of the path ..

App.jsx

```
import Card from './components/Card';
import KatieZ from '../images/katie-zaferes.png'

export default function App() {

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Navbar />
      <Hero />
      <Card 
        img={Katiez}
        rating="5.0"
        reviewCount={6}
        country="USA"
        title="Life lessons with Katie Zaferes"
        price={42}
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Cards.jsx

```
import "../css/index.css"
import Star from '../images/star.png'

function Card(props) {

    return (
      <section className="experience-cards">
        <div className="experience-item">
            <img className="card-image" src={props.img} alt="Olympic athlete Katie Zaferes"/>
            <p className="experience-text">Sold Out</p>
        </div>
        <div className="description-below">
            <div className="rating">
                <img className="star" src={Star} alt="Rating star" width={15}/>
                <p>{props.rating}</p><span>({props.reviewCount}) • {props.country}</span>
            </div>
            <p class="item-description">{props.title}</p>
            <p className="item-price"><span className="item-price">From ${props.price}</span> /  person</p>
        </div>
      </section>
    )
  }
  
  export default Card
```

Answer (score 1):

[React 18 Video Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=18RdrMyTwY8) helped me to find out how to deal with images in React 18. We can host images in different places:

1. On local server, **public** folder:

   ```
    <Card img="./images/katie-zaferes.png">
   ```

   To make this work we need in the `public` folder of our project to create `images` folder and place there `katie-zaferes.png` file. So the file's location in the project will be: `public/images/katie-zaferes.png`
2. On local server, **src** folder:

   ```
    <Card img="../images/katie-zaferes.png" />
   ```

   Our image is in the `src/images` folder, so we need to import it like any other file:

   ```
    import katie from '../images/katie-zaferes.png'

    <Card img={katie} />
   ```

   It's better solution for assets, since under the hood they get optimized.
3. On external server. In this case we need absolute URL:

   ```
    <Card img="https://cdn.some.com/abc..x/katie-zaferes.png" />
   ```